Excel VBA deleting rows based on specific value
I have a marcro that is supposed to do the following:
If double click on cell in column B and the content of the cell = "Delete Chapter" it should start to run the macro, the Macro should identify the chapter number (which is stated in column E). then the Macro should delete all rows if the chapter number stated in column F = the previously identified chapter number.
Somehow the Macro is not working and it gives me the error that there is no matching id found in column F, but there are matching id's in column F.

    Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    ' Check if the double-click was made in column B
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        ' Check if the value of the clicked cell is "DELETE CHAPTER"
        If Target.Value = "DELETE CHAPTER" Then
            
            Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
            Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("BoQ")
            Dim LastRow As Long
            Dim id1 As Variant
            Dim i As Long
            Dim found As Boolean
            
            ' Get the ID from column E (3 columns to the right of column B)
            id1 = Target.Offset(0, 3).Value
            
            ' Check if ID is found in column A of "BoQ" sheet
            If id1 = "" Then
                MsgBox "ID in column E is empty. Cannot proceed."
                Exit Sub
            End If

            ' Find the last row in column A (assuming IDs are in column A)
            LastRow = ws.Range("F" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            
            ' Initialize 'found' flag to track if any row matches the ID
            found = False
            
            ' Loop through the rows in the "BoQ" sheet, starting from the bottom
            For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
                If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = id1 Then
                    ws.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
                    found = True ' Set flag if a row is deleted
                End If
            Next i
            
            ' Check if any row was deleted
            If found Then
                MsgBox "Row(s) deleted successfully."
            Else
                MsgBox "No matching ID found in column F."
            End If
            
        Else
            ' If not "DELETE CHAPTER", keep selection in the active cell
            Target.Select
        End If
        
        ' Cancel the default double-click action
        Cancel = True
        
        ' Hide rows 1 to 6
        Rows("1:6").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

End Sub


Are the chapters in the same sheet as the column B:B that you are supposed to double click on? Also: a sample of the data you are working with would be helpful to reproduce your problem.

@EvilBlueMonkey I have added a screenshot, as i believe adding an excel file to this website is not possible?

A Worksheet BeforeDoubleClick: Delete Matching Rows

Assuming the chapter IDs in column F are consecutive, one row below the other, and for each chapter, they start one row above the target cell.

Sheet Module, e.g. Sheet1(BoQ)
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    DeleteChapter Target, Cancel
End Sub

Standard Module, e.g. Module1 renamed to modEvents

(to not clutter the sheet module)

Sub DeleteChapter(ByVal Target As Range, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)

    Const TARGET_TOP_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "B12"
    Const TARGET_CRITERIA_STRING = "DELETE CHAPTER"
    Const CHAPTER_ID_COLUMN As String = "F"
    Const CHAPTER_ID_ROW_OFFSET As Long = -1
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Target.Worksheet
    
    Dim trg As Range, tRowsCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range(TARGET_TOP_CELL_ADDRESS)
        tRowsCount = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, .Column).End(xlUp).Row - .Row + 1
        If tRowsCount < 1 Then Exit Sub
        Set trg = .Resize(tRowsCount)
    End With
    
    If Intersect(Target, trg) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim tString As String: tString = CStr(Target.Value)
    If StrComp(tString, TARGET_CRITERIA_STRING, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim ChapterID As Long, ChapterRowsCount As Long
    
    With Target.EntireRow.Columns(CHAPTER_ID_COLUMN) _
            .Offset(CHAPTER_ID_ROW_OFFSET)
        ChapterID = .Value
        ChapterRowsCount = 1 - CHAPTER_ID_ROW_OFFSET
        Do While .Offset(ChapterRowsCount).Value = ChapterID
            ChapterRowsCount = ChapterRowsCount + 1
        Loop
        .Resize(ChapterRowsCount).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    End With

    Cancel = True

End Sub

